# Back button in Android activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

If the **back** button in android is to destroy the activity or flush activity from the memory, then my question is why there is still the activity is shown after the **overview** button is pressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "overview" button shows the **list of recent tasks**. Even after all of the activities in an app have finished (ie: none of them are running or active), Android still remembers this in the list of recent tasks. That is why the app is shown in the list.